# Can't write to file immediately after creation

Tags: c#, file, io, hidden, file-attributes

In the following code:

```
if (File.Exists(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData) + "/data.dat"))
{
    File.AppendAllText(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData) + "/data.dat", temp);
}
else
{
    File.Create(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData) + "/data.dat");
    File.SetAttributes(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData) + "/data.dat", FileAttributes.Hidden);
    File.AppendAllText(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData) + "/data.dat", temp);
}
```

for some reason, the first time this code is run, it creates the file just fine, but does not write to it, and it will not until i exit the app, and re-run it. the 2nd, 3rd, and so on runs work just fine, its just the initial that's screwy. any ideas? file names and directories are random since i was just testing something so you should be able to change those to whatever you want if you're testing something. Thanks in advance

Comment: What's the full exception text/exact problem?

Comment: Piotr Auguscik(below) answered it. there was no exception.

Answer (score 7):

You should put **.Close()** after **File.Create**

```
File.Create(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData) + "/data.dat").Close();
```

Read more at [MSDN File.Create](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d62kzs03.aspx)

or You can do this

```
File.WriteAllText(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData) + "/data.dat", temp);         
File.SetAttributes(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData) + "/data.dat", FileAttributes.Hidden);
```

Read more at [MSDN File.WriteAllText](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143356.aspx)

Answer (score 6):

`File.Create` is returning you stream to file you might want to close it before you try to reopen it again.

Answer (score 4):

File.AppendAllText() will create the file if it does not already exist, so you could just do:

```
File.AppendAllText(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData) + "/data.dat", temp);         
File.SetAttributes(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData) + "/data.dat", FileAttributes.Hidden);
```

See if that helps :)

Answer (score 3):

Skip creating the file, the AppendAllText method creates it anyway if it's not there.
I'm guessing the file.create might leave a file lock or file handle open.

Comment: No need to guess. File.Create() does keep a handle open until the stream created is closed/disposed.